# Biggest sale of every employee on Northwind?

Tags: t-sql, northwind

I'm trying to list the biggest sale of each employee on Northwind database, and so far the best I could do is this;

```
select top (select count(EmployeeID) from Employees)     
    max(Quantity*OrderDetails.UnitPrice) TotalSale, FirstName+' '+LastName Name, ProductName  from Orders 
left join OrderDetails
    on
        OrderDetails.OrderID=Orders.OrderID
left join Employees
    on
        Orders.EmployeeID=Employees.EmployeeID
left join Products
    on
        OrderDetails.ProductID=Products.ProductID

group by FirstName,LastName, ProductName

order by TotalSale desc
```

But even though I used the group by I get repeated records;

```
TotalSale             Name                            ProductName
15810,00              Andrew Fuller                   Côte de Blaye
15810,00              Nancy Davolio                   Côte de Blaye
10540,00              Robert King                     Côte de Blaye
10540,00              Anne Dodsworth                  Côte de Blaye
10540,00              Margaret Peacock                Côte de Blaye
9903,20               Janet Leverling                 Thüringer Rostbratwurst
8432,00               Steven Buchanan                 Côte de Blaye
7905,00               Janet Leverling                 Côte de Blaye
7427,40               Andrew Fuller                   Thüringer Rostbratwurst
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

(9 row(s) affected)
```

So I have 9 employees and I used top function for that but the employees are not unique, I also tried to use distinct function but it didn't work either.

So I would appreciate a hand please!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you also group by productname. So you will get max sales per employee and per product name.

What you can do is, drop the product name in group by, in this case you will see max total sales only per employee.

```
select max(Quantity*OrderDetails.UnitPrice) TotalSale, FirstName+' '+LastName Name
from Orders 
left join [Order Details] as OrderDetails on OrderDetails.OrderID=Orders.OrderID
left join Employees on Orders.EmployeeID=Employees.EmployeeID
left join Products on OrderDetails.ProductID=Products.ProductID
group by FirstName,LastName
order by TotalSale desc
```

In case you want to see the product name as well, you can encapsulate your query in a subquery and create a rownum based on employee name and order by total sales. You can select rows with rownum 1 in the outer query. Use rank function in case you need to show all occurances of product names.

```
SELECT TotalSale, Name, ProductName
FROM
(
    select max(Quantity*OrderDetails.UnitPrice) TotalSale
        ,FirstName + ' ' + LastName Name
        ,ProductName
        ,Rnk = Rank() OVER(PARTITION BY Employees.EmployeeId ORDER BY MAX(Quantity*OrderDetails.UnitPrice) DESC)
    from Orders 
    left join [Order Details] as OrderDetails on OrderDetails.OrderID=Orders.OrderID
    left join Employees on Orders.EmployeeID=Employees.EmployeeID
    left join Products on OrderDetails.ProductID=Products.ProductID
    group by FirstName,LastName, Employees.EmployeeId, ProductName
) as sub
where sub.Rnk = 1
order by Name
```

Comment: I understand your solution about productname but i can't seem to make it work. Terribly sorry. Can you show me how would you do it?